# githab. pycharm, удаленный репозиторий

Tags: github, pycharm

В пайчарме создано приложение, но оно не отображается в Гитхабе, что нужно сделать для того чтобы созданное приложение появилось в гитхабе?

Comment: Создать репозиторий на гитхабе как минимум. Инициализировать локальный репозиторий в проекте. Запушить локлаьный репозиторий на гитхаб.

Comment: как самый-самый минимум надо учётную запись создать. на сайте github.com